# Different models order in main.django_content_type table during unittesting

Tags: django, sqlite, unit-testing, content-type

I'm using django 3.1 with SQLite DB. I'm using my django project as API, so django rest framework is installed as well. During my unittest (with pycharm) I've observed that in table main.django_content_type some models in my dev DB and test DB are ordered differently and have different IDs. For example **defaultcategory** and **customcategory**:

**dev DB:**

1. admin   logentry
2. auth    permission
3. auth    group
4. contenttypes    contenttype
5. sessions    session
6. core    customuser
7. core    historicalcustomuser
8. authtoken   token
9. authtoken   historicaltoken
10. finances    fixtransaction
11. finances    historicaldefaultcategory
12. finances    historicaltransfer
13. finances    historicaltransaction
14. finances    transaction
15. finances    fixtransfer
16. finances    historicalfixtransfer
17. finances    historicalcostaccount
18. finances    historicalfixtransaction
19. finances    transfer
20. finances    costaccount
21. finances    historicalcustomcategory
22. **finances  defaultcategory**
23. **finances  customcategory**

**test DB:**

1. admin | log entry
2. auth | permission
3. auth | group
4. contenttypes | content type
5. sessions | session
6. core | custom user
7. core | historical custom user
8. finances | cost account
9. finances | transfer
10. finances | transaction
11. finances | historical transfer
12. finances | historical transaction
13. finances | historical fix transfer
14. finances | historical fix transaction
15. finances | historical default category
16. finances | historical custom category
17. finances | historical cost account
18. finances | fix transfer
19. finances | fix transaction
20. **finances | default category**
21. **finances | custom category**
22. authtoken | Token
23. authtoken | historical Token

Is there any way to sort all model during the test in the same way they are in dev DB?